# Add HTML to server form when dynamically adding form elements ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I have a DB table that stores custom fields for certain forms. I am building these forms dynamically from the code behind and it works, but it looks bad. I want to be able to wrap the form in a table.

I have the following code to dynamically create the form elements. By using a loop i can create a label and input box for each of the custom fields

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = field["fieldname"];
newclientform.Controls.Add(label);

TextBox textinput = new TextBox();
textinput.ID = field["uiname"];
newclientform.Controls.Add(textinput);
```

All of the static form elements are correctly wrapped in HTML as i can write this into the aspx file, but none of these dynamic elements are wrapped in HTML.
I tried the following, but none of the HTML is rendered

```
label.Text = "<tr><th>" + field["fieldname"] + "</th></tr>";
```

How can i wrap these form elements in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use repeater, or any other similar feature. Create a repeater at codebehind, use literal object to insert the proper html tags and then put your textboxes, and close it with another literal.

Literal is the cleanest object to send your HTML codes to interface, since Label object are rendered with unnecessary HTML tags, which might be causing your problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First, my English was poor.
In your way, I don't know if you can make it or not, 
but I think you need try this control----PlaceHolder.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolderId" runat="server">
     on here, you can write any dom element
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

in code behind, like that--------

```
 placeHolderId.Controls.Add(yourControlObject);
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but how do i add multiple? i dont know how many custom fields there will be. might be 1 might be 10. how can i create multiple placeholders with unique IDs? ASP.net doesnt allow for dynamic IDs other wise i wouldnt need to use code behind

Comment: the best way to add dom into page is Ajax, WebForm has something Shortcomings, such as when page postback, some control's data will reset, you have to judge  if(Page.IsPostBack == true)，especially DropDownList. But, if you choose Ajax, you just need serialize the data into json and write into response's stream. So, use javascript's "XMLHttpRequest" object to receive and--- var obj =JSON.Prase(xmlHttpRequestObj); into a object, and  for( attribute in obj){  package obj[attribute] into a dom, and add into page }. I'm sorry, my English is poor, and I don't know how to change code style on comment

Comment: PlaceHolder has ability to add any amounts control------placeHodlerId.Control.Add(ctrl1); placeHolder.Control.Add(ctrl2); placeHolder.Control.Add(ctrl3); and more, no problem.